# Как удалить из массива jquery лишние фрагменты строк в элементах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив на `js`, подключена библиотека `jquery`

```
labels=['0 (-100%)','1','2 (+100%)','3 (+200%)','4 (+300%)','5 (+400%)','6 (+500%)','7 (+600%)','8 (+700%)','9 (+800%)','10']
```

Как из него элементов удалить проценты в скобках вместе с пробелом `(-100%)` оставив только цифры в таком виде:

```
labels=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
```

Comment: Что это странный синтаксис массива? Осмелюсь предположить, что такого массива не может быть. Может, у вас это строка?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko массив строковых значений, подправил

Comment: если элементы массива всегда имеют такую запись то самый простой способ это для каждого элемента массива сделать `split` по пробелу и взять первый элемент, иначе регуляркой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализованное предложение от @Bald.

```js
const labels = ['0 (-100%)', '1', '2 (+100%)', '3 (+200%)', '4 (+300%)', '5 (+400%)', '6 (+500%)', '7 (+600%)', '8 (+700%)', '9 (+800%)', '10'];
const digits = labels.map(m => m.split(' ')[0]);
console.log(digits);
```

Самый быстрый способ - `indexOf` совместно с `substr`.

https://jsperf.com/parse-number-in-string

```js
const cnt = 1000000;
const labels2 = new Array(cnt);

for (let i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
  labels2[i] = i + ' ' + 'dasd';
}

console.time('split');
const res1 = labels2.map(m => m.split(' ')[0]);
console.timeEnd('split');

console.time('parseInt');
const res2 = labels2.map(m => parseInt(m).toString());
console.timeEnd('parseInt');

console.time('parseFloat');
const res3 = labels2.map(m => parseFloat(m).toString());
console.timeEnd('parseFloat');


console.time('indexOf');
const res4 = labels2.map(m => m.substr(0, m.indexOf(' ')));
console.timeEnd('indexOf');
```

Comment: Да тут и `parseInt` подойдет, без всяких `split`.  Так-как первым идет число, оно приведет к числу, а остальное отсеет. Да и быстрее в разы будет.

Comment: @And а можно еще и регуляркой сделать. А можно еще и `indexOf` использовать, и `parseFloat`. В чем смысл Вашего комментария?

Comment: Однако вы, выбрали самый медленный вариант, гениально! И да кстати о птичках, `indexOf` - без использования дополнительных функций  вам этого сделать не удастся.

Comment: @And Вы всегда можете оставить свой ответ. И преждевременная оптимизация - зло.

Comment: @And насколько я понимаю, `parseInt` приведет значения к числовым и он не будет нужного вида
`labels=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']`, а будет 
`labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`?

Comment: @Вася да, так и будет. Хотя это не сильно большая проблема - число всегда можно преобразовать в стринг.

Comment: @And в Opera 58 версии `parseInt` оказался самым медленным :D